# Leverage browser cache set header

Tags: nginx, browser-cache

I setup the server (nginx) and now the response contains the following:
- Cache-Control: max-age=21600,public
- ETag: "5a50db96-1f04"
- Expires: Sat, 06 Jan 2018 22:17:45 GMT
- Last-Modified: Sat, 06 Jan 2018 14:22:14 GMT

but when I check using google page insight or gtmetrix it is says: There are ... static components without a far-future expiration date or laverage cache warning.

I really dont know what is the problem..... because the content comes from my server and I set it right.

Comment: 21600 seconds is 6 days, which doesn’t qualify as a “far-future expiration date” to me. The `Expires` also conflicts with it and shouldn’t even be there.

Comment: I set it to 1 hour but nothing changed and they has a problem with it. Cache-Control max-age=3600, public, no-transform
ETag"5a50db96-1f04"
Expires Sat, 06 Jan 2018 17:52:08 GMT
Last-Modified Sat, 06 Jan 2018 14:22:14 GMT

Comment: 1 hour is less than 6 days, so if 6 days doesn’t qualify as “far-future”, 1 hour won’t either.

Comment: Yes you are right, I am a stupid, sorry and thank you!